# Least cumulative distance for plotter to plot 'n' points

Tags: algorithm, coordinates, distance

There is given a plotter which can plot points provided to it in the form of 'x' and 'y' coordinates. The plotter hand can move horizontally or vertically only. Input will be provided in the form of a list of 'n' coordinates: {(x1,y1), (x2,y2} ... (xn,yn)}. Initially, the plotter would be at origin.

It's required to provide an algo to return a list of all 'n' points that would represent the least cumulative distance for the plotter hand to plot all 'n' points in the exact order provided in the output list.

*With some initial reminisce, I am tempted to think that the output would a list of 'n' points sorted with increasing 'x' and 'y' co-ordinates.*

For instance,

**Input**-  (3, 5), (1, 2), (4, 3)

**Output**- (1, 2), (3, 5), (4, 3)

But, I am afraid that this would be the correct algorithm.

So, the question is: derive an algorithm to solve this problem and if the above is correct, then prove it.

Also, what changes will the derived algorithm observe *if the plotter were also allowed to move diagonally!*

Comment: This is the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). The diagonal move version is Euclidean TSP. The Manhattan distance version is also a metric TSP. Both forms are NP-hard. You can solve exactly for small sizes, but for larger problems you will need to go with an approximation. Your algorithm would give a non-optimal result if the points form two rows on opposite sides of the board: (1,0), (1,100), (2,0), (2,100)...

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan can you explain how is it TSP? And if it's indeed TSP, then how many edges will the graph have? As far as I can think, from every co-ordinate (node) there will (n-1) edges.

Comment: "Given a list of cities and the distances between each pair of cities, what is the shortest possible route that visits each city exactly once and returns to the origin city?" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) The only differences I can see is "city" vs. "point", and whether return to origin is required, which does not make much difference. The referenced article discusses general metric distance and Euclidean distance versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is an NP-hard variant of the Traveling Salesman Problem, so exact solution is practical only for small problems. See [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) for a general description. [Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Free_software_for_solving_TSP) has links to some programs that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As Patricia already wrote in her comment, this is equivalent to the metric Traveling Salesman problem with Manhattan distance. It is an NP-complete optimization problem and is best solved with an approximation or heuristic algorithm for real-life problems (say more than 10 points to plot). Any deterministic algorithm that always produces an optimal solution is likely going to scale extremely badly to larger problem sizes.